# npm package: react-share - Not able to share images in social media platforms

Tags: reactjs, whatsapp, social-media, react-share

Problem Statement:

1. When user clicks share button icon-> options: whatsapp, twitter, etc...
2. react-share npm has URL and Title as options to their Share buttons. Ex: WhatsappShareButton and others..
3. I am only able to share "base64 string" format in URL option of Share buttons.As URL option takes only string input.
4. Not getting image from base64 string when sent to URL option.

Expected Behaviour: Image from base64 string When shared to social media platforms.

1. I want to send base64 string to this URL option of Share buttons, but when i share its giving back the string not image. Shown in following picture.
   [tried to send base64 string to URL option expected the image from base64, but got base64 string only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd0mB.png)
2. Expecting I get image like this..[Base64 string to im](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4RM.jpg)

Whatsapp image and text as description..